# Maintaining old project on Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

I have some old Windows projects written 10+ years ago with Delphi 7, which need some minor changes now.
I still have Delphi 7 installation somewhere, but not sure it is good idea to install it on modern Windows10 PC...
Are there any newer compilers compatible with Delphi7?

Comment: Install Delphi 7 on Windows 10.

Comment: You can install Delphi 7 on Windows 10. You should avoid installing it into Program Files, because it isn't aware of modern restrictions against writing files there. Any folder directly off your C: drive should work fine. There is no *newer compiler compatible with Delphi 7. because just like all other things based on technology, things have changed over the last couple of decades.

Comment: You can do what @Ken says, that's a simple and safe way to do it. I install in the program files directory and you just need to add a permissive ACL to make it work. If you don't know what that is, do what Ken suggests!

Comment: You could always make an XP VM and install D7 into that. It will be quite comfortable in there.